# How do I run Docker IBM MQ for Developers on Windows?

Tags: docker, ibm-mq

How do I run [Docker IBM MQ for Developers](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/mq/) on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have [installed docker on windows](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/), the command is:

```
docker run \
  --env LICENSE=accept \
  --env MQ_QMGR_NAME=QM1 \
  --publish 1414:1414 \
  --publish 9443:9443 \
  --detach \
  ibmcom/mq
```

Comment: Why publish both 1414 and 9443 ? I assume it's localhost:1414 and localholst:9443 ?

Answer (score 0):

Docker isolates processes from the host OS, it is not a virtual machine technology [where there is a guest and host OS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pG94I.png). When running Docker you have access to only one operating system. Since IBM MQ images are Linux images, it will be challenging to run them on Windows.

You could try running the [LinuxKit on Docker Windows](https://blog.docker.com/2017/09/preview-linux-containers-on-windows/) and then start the IBM MQ container.

Another option is a workaround, use Linux to run Docker instead of Windows. You can set up a Linux VM on Windows using for example [VirtualBox](https://www.lifewire.com/run-ubuntu-within-windows-virtualbox-2202098). If you do not want to use a VM on your laptop, you can use a free [AWS EC2 tier to run a Linux VM and install IBM MQ for Developers there](https://trafficparrot.com/tutorials/How_run_a_free_Docker_IBM_MQ_for_Developers_on_Windows_Linux_and_AWS.html).